# How to put in different Listview?

Tags: xml, jquery, jquery-mobile

My jquery codes to get Name,code and category:

```
     $(req.responseText).find("Table").each(function(i) {
              var item = $(this),
              name = item.find('Name').text(),
              code = item.find('Code').text(),
              catg = item.find('Category').text();                    

                 var $content = $('<li><a href="#"><img src="../../img/album-bb.jpg"><h3>Name: '+ name + '</h3><p>Code: '+ code + '</p><p>Category: '+ catg + '</p></a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Add to favorites</a></li>');                              
                 $('#RecipeList').append($content).listview('refresh');



      });
```

this my sample response of my XML:

```
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <Code>106377</Code>
    <Name>Blackened red snapper</Name>
    <Category>123</Category>
    <Yield>4</Yield>
    <YieldUnit/>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
    <Code>303570</Code>
    <Name>Celery soup</Name>
    <Category>123</Category>
    <Yield>1</Yield>
    <YieldUnit/>
</Table>
<Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
    <Code>303675</Code>
    <Name>Challah French Toast</Name>
    <Category>123</Category>
    <Yield>6</Yield>
    <YieldUnit/>
   </Table>
```

the listview ouput is this:

```
Name: Blackened red snapperCelerySoupChallah French toast
Code: 106377303570303675
Category: 123123123
```

How to put in different listview?..when its append.Thanks

Comment: What is a different listview for you? And what is your problem?

Comment: i mean the output of listview is like this: Name : Blackened red snapper Code: 106377 Category: 123 Name : Celery Soup Code: 303570 Category: 123 Name: Challah french toast Code: 303675 Category 123.

Comment: its formatted like a listview but all the data is on one(1)list view only instead there is three(3) listview expected to exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ni = 0;
var ci = 0;
var cati = 0;
var NameArr = new Array();
var CodeArr = new Array();
var CatArr  = new Array();

$(req.responseText).find('Name').each(function () {
  NameArr[ni] = $(this).text();
  ni++;
}

$(req.responseText).find('Code').each(function () {
  CodeArr[ci] = $(this).text();
  ci++;
}

$(req.responseText).find('Category').each(function () {
  CatArr[cati] = $(this).text();
  cati++;
}

for(var i=0; i<NameArr.length; i++){
    var $content = $('<li><a href="#"><img src="../../img/album-bb.jpg"><h3>Name: '+ NameArr[i] + '</h3><p>Code: '+ CodeArr[i]+ '</p><p>Category: '+ CatArr[i]+ '</p></a><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Add to favorites</a></li>');                              
    $('#RecipeList').append($content).listview('refresh');
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. If my answer was useful, kindly upvote, I can use some points ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/uzphF/

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#table-data').empty();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/echo/xml/",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            xml: '<Tables><Table><Code>106377</Code><Name>Blackened red snapper</Name><Category>123</Category><Yield>4</Yield><YieldUnit/></Table><Table><Code>303570</Code><Name>Celery soup</Name><Category>123</Category><Yield>1</Yield><YieldUnit/></Table><Table><Code>303675</Code><Name>Challah French Toast</Name><Category>123</Category><Yield>6</Yield><YieldUnit/></Table></Tables>'
        },
        success: function(xml) {
            ajax.parseXML(xml);
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred!');
        }
    });
});

var ajax = {  
    parseXML:function(result){
        $(result).find("Table").each(function(){
            var code  = $(this).find('Code').text();
            var name  = $(this).find('Name').text();
            var cat  = $(this).find('Category').text();
            var yield  = $(this).find('Yield').text();

            $('#table-data').append('<li><a href="#cars"><h3>Table code:<span> '+code+'</span></h3><p>Table name: ' + name + '</p></a></li>');
        });    
        $('#table-data').listview('refresh');
    }
}
```

This example used mockup jsFiddle function to test XML ajax call, but this part is not essential. Only thing you need to know is how to loop through XML. One more thing, your XML example must be wrapped in parent tag, I named it **tables**.